# I can't send string with messaging center in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can send object when I use a class like this.

```cs
MessagingCenter.Send<CariRoot>(selectedCari, "mselectedCari");
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CariRoot>(this, "mselectedCari" ,async (sender) =>
{
    SearchCari = $"{sender.CARIUNVAN}";
    _SelectedCariRoot = sender;

    Console.WriteLine(SearchCari);
});
```

But when I want to send a string not an object I use MessagingCenter like this and this code doesn't work. I can't figure how to send a string.

```cs
MessagingCenter.Send<string>(searchText, "searchText"); 
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "searchText", async (sender) =>
{
    SearchStateText = $"{sender}";
});
```

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Make sure to follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center). AFAIK, `string` cannot be the `TSender` type. It should be one of your classes/pages.

Comment: As @julian says, read the docs.  `Send<T1,T2>` where `T1` is the type of the **sender**, and `T2` is the type of the **payload**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter.send) method specifies two generic arguments. The first is the type that's sending the message, and the second is the type of the payload data being sent. To receive the message, a subscriber must also specify the same generic arguments. This enables multiple messages that share a message identity but send different payload data types to be received by different subscribers.

In addition, this example specifies a third method argument that represents the payload data to be sent to the subscriber. In this case the payload data is a `string`.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "searchText", "John");

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page, string>(this, "searchText", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    await DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + arg, "OK");
});
```